# Keep range limits when filter is set. Function. Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that looks up a value inside a given range.

When I filter that range in Excel though, the function only uses the filter range instead of the complete range.

My code:

```
Function LastTwoYearsByRegion(category As String, region As String, quality As String, strType As String) As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long

    LastTwoYearsByRegion = 0

    lastRow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'more code following here

End Function
```

It looks as if my `lastRow` variable keeps changing when the filter is used. How can I prevent the function from doing exactly that and instead always use the complete range?

Comment: Either **A)** calculate the `LastRow` variable _before_ filtering and pass it into your `Function()`, or **B)** un-filter within the `Function()`, get `LastRow` then re-filter. I think option A would be much easier. [Gary's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30105972/2344413) answer isn't bad, but if other people are going to be using the worksheet, there's no guarantee your little marker will remain or that it won't be overwritten when additional data is entered.

Comment: It is a UDF and will recalculate.

Answer (score 0):

I cheat!!

I include a special value **two** rows below the bottom of the filtered table:

[image]

and then, no matter what filtering I apply, this macro:

```
Public Function GetLastRow()
    GetLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 2
End Function
```

will get me what I need:

[image]

Comment: The only drawback is if someone else uses the worksheet, doesn't know why `xxx` is in some random cell, and deletes it in an effort to keep the sheet clean. I'm pretty sure that's something I'd do if I saw that...

Comment: The point is that BOTH codes do the same thing.......Having the **xxx** cell allows the code to accurately find the last cell in the table because the **xxx** is never hidden.....it is beyond the filter range!

Comment: Does this mean that the `.Row` property of filtered cells is manipulated?

Comment: **NO**  *Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row* starts from the bottom of a sheet and "looks" upwards to find the first "visible cell".  When you filter cells,some cells become non-visible and the code just doesn't see them.

Comment: Is there a way of getting my `lastRow` from the Cells-collection instead of the sheet?